# cant install wine on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wine, dependencies

I have try everything, it always appears like

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try each of them before installing. Some may produce errors.

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get remove wine`
- `sudo apt-get autoclean clean`
- `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` then `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`
- Lastly, if nothing works, try installing aptitude instead of apt-get.:

Install Aptitude:

- `sudo apt-get install aptitude`
- `sudo aptitude install wine`